# Magento 2.2.3 API retuning HTML code while integration between Magento 2.2.3 & Linnworks

Tags: api, magento2.2, html, magento2.2.3

**Request send**

```
POST http://exhaustkings.co.uk/backup/rest/V1/integration/admin/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Linnworks client
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: exhaustkings.co.uk

{"username":"[username]","password":"[password]"}
```

**Response we receive:**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1148
Date: Wed, 02 May 2018 14:36:23 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: Keep-Alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head><title> 404 Not Found
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;"><h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">404</h1><h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Not Found</h2><p>The resource requested could not be found on this server!</p>
</div></div><div style="color:#f0f0f0; font-size:12px;margin:auto;padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;position:relative;clear:both;height:100px;margin-top:-101px;background-color:#474747;border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;">
<br>Proudly powered by  <a style="color:#fff;" href="http://www.litespeedtech.com/error-page">LiteSpeed Web Server</a><p>Please be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found on this site.</p></div></body></html>
```

And I cannot find no "rest" folder anywhere under my Magento directory.

Comment: Check your url. It looks like `http://exhaustkings.co.uk/backup/` does not run any magento installation.

Comment: The website is there, I can see it on my end. http://exhaustkings.co.uk/backup/

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong api url

**Use api url:**

```
http://exhaustkings.co.uk/backup/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```

**instead of**

```
http://exhaustkings.co.uk/backup/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```